# Can adverbs modify auxiliaries?

Tags: sentence-meaning

An adverb modifies an adjective, an adverb, and a verb, then  an auxiliary verb can be modified or described by a preposition phrase or adverbs? Feel free to say anything.

Comment: Do you mind providing some examples in reference to the context.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh 'I can study in my room' to express that I don't study in my room, but I'm able to study in my room.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh I mean I have an ability for study in my room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q. Can adverbs modify auxiliaries?

Yes. Verbs and auxillary verbs work together to form a single idea. You can't really say that an adverb works on one but not the other. An adverb would work on *both* together.

Example:

1. John **is** at university.
2. John is **currently** at university.
3. John **is** currently **going** to university.
4. John **currently goes** to university.

In example 2, I added an adverb "currently" which modifies the verb "is". In example 3, the original verb "is" becomes the auxillary to the main verb "going", but the adverb modifies the meaning of the sentence in exactly the same way. As you can see from example 4, I removed the auxillary verb and the meaning remains the same as examples 2 and 3.